# How to shelve\save my pending changes in VS 2017 without being connected to TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfvc, shelveset

I changes to the code but I disconnected from the TFS.
I want to connect to TFS but I am worried that my pending changes will disappear.
I know that shelve is great way to save your work but I can't because as I said I am disconnected from the TFS.
If someone have any idea or way to save the work it will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't shelve while disconnected. Most activities in TFVC require a connection, including shelving.

Connecting to your TFVC repo should not cause you to lose your work, but if you're concerned about it, my recommendation is to make a copy of the folder containing your source code temporarily.